# CPU player dice game

Tags: python

Need to program a CPU that decides between throwing the dice again or ending its turn.

The game already works with two players. Now I just need the 2nd player to make decisions on its own.

What do I do? This is a part of the code:

```
while not juego_termina:
print("")
jug_turno.lanzar_dado(dado)
jug2.dec_cpu()
while jug_turno.jugando:
    jug2.dec_cpu()                                         #Se anida un while para cada turno del jugador
    print("Puntaje parcial acumulado:",end=' ')
    print(jug_turno.p_parcial)
    continuar = ""
    jug2.dec_cpu()
    while continuar != "SI" and continuar != "NO":         #Pregunta si continua el turno
        print("Desea seguir jugando? (SI/NO)")

        continuar = input().upper()                        #.upper para la mayuscula
    if continuar == "SI":
        jug_turno.lanzar_dado(dado)
    else:
        jug_turno.terminar_turno()
if jug_turno.p_total >= meta:                             #Compara el puntaje total con la meta asignada al inicio
    juego_termina = True                                  #Se acaba el juego y salta a nombrar el ganador
else:
    if jug_turno == jug1:
        jug_turno = jug2
    else:
        jug_turno = jug1
mostrar_puntajes(jug1,jug2)
```

print("El ganador es:")
print(jug_turno.nombre)

Comment: Is the question "how do I use different logic for the human player (who provides input manually) and the computer player (who decides whether to roll again based on some algorithm)?", or is the question "what logic should the computer player use to decide whether to roll again?"

Comment: How to make the CPU( which is substuting player 2 ) decide whether to throw the dice or end the turn, as would a real person.

It already works with 2 real players. Now I just need to implement the CPU

Answer (score 0):

I only know a small amount of Spanish, so it's possible I'm reading your code incorrectly, but it looks like the game works like Blackjack - the winning player is the player who has the highest total without going over some maximum value (21 in the case of Blackjack). The code for the simplest algorithm you could use probably looks something like this:

```
def dec_cpu(maximum):
    total = 0
    while total < maximum and (highest_possible_die_roll / 2)  < (maximum - total):
        total = total + roll_die()
    return total
```

The `(highest_possible_die_roll / 2)  < (maximum - total)` part is essentially saying, "if there's less than a 50% chance that rolling the die again will put me over the maximum, roll again". From there, you can refine it depending on the rules of the game. For example, if there's an amount of money being wagered each time, the computer might want to be 75% sure that they won't go over the maximum when the die is rolled if there's a lot of money on the line.

Comment: Tried doing the " total < maximum and (highest_possible_die_roll / 2)  < (maximum - total):" part but it always keeps rolling the dice, never stops.

Comment: Hmm - hard to know what to do there without seeing the code. I'd probably add a statement to the loop to print all of the variables out each time through and make sure they're changing the way you expect (it should be just the total that keeps increasing).